# Android EditContactActivity source

Tags: android, android-source

Android EditContactActivity contains the functionality when + button is pressed new field is added to listview and - button delete that extra field. I need this exact functionality, but I could not find it in Android source code.
How to extract this particular functionality? And if someone can tell me how to understand android source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember correctly it's not a ListView at all actually, more like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            All the editors go here
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
            Buttons and stuff goes here
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically they're adding and removing items in a LinearLayout at the right position.

If you want to look into the specifics a (complete?) mirror of the Android repo is up at github - the contacts app, for instance, is here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need more to know how can i find the + & - minus buttons name what method is called when they are clicked how new field is generated and deleted. I be very grateful if you can teach me how can i understand the android source code means how can i find particular functionality, resources, usages etc etc